# PromQL, Grafana - Count how many times metric's labels values has changed

Tags: grafana, promql, prometheus-pushgateway

I'm trying to count how many times Metric_x changed it's labels.

In Prometheus I have 4 metrics: Metric_1, Metric_2, Metric_3, Metric_4.

If I use the query `{__name__=~"Metric_\d"}`, I get the following output:

In table:

```
Metric_1{buildURL="job/Onboarding_Test/2/", job="test_test", line="22"} 1
Metric_2{buildURL="job/Onboarding_Test/2/", job="test_test", line="33"} 1
Metric_3{buildURL="job/Onboarding_Test/7/", job="test_test", line="33"} 1 
Metric_4{buildURL="job/Onboarding_Test/2/", job="test_test", line="11"} 1
```

In Graph's legend:

```
Metric_1{buildURL="job/Onboarding_Test/1/", job="test_test", line="33"}
Metric_1{buildURL="job/Onboarding_Test/2/", job="test_test", line="22"}
Metric_2{buildURL="job/Onboarding_Test/1/", job="test_test", line="11"}
Metric_2{buildURL="job/Onboarding_Test/2/", job="test_test", line="33"}
Metric_2{buildURL="job/Onboarding_Test/3/", job="test_test", line="22"}
Metric_3{buildURL="job/Onboarding_Test/2/", job="test_test", line="11"}
Metric_3{buildURL="job/Onboarding_Test/6/", job="test_test", line="11"}
Metric_3{buildURL="job/Onboarding_Test/7/", job="test_test", line="33"}
Metric_4{buildURL="job/Onboarding_Test/2/", job="test_test", line="11"}
```

I want to visualise in Grafana (table view) how many times Metrics changes their labels values. (Changes I can see in "Graph tab" in Prometheus)

Expected output:

| name | val |
| --- | --- |
| Metric_1 | 2 |
| Metric_2 | 3 |
| Metric_3 | 3 |
| Metric_4 | 1 |

Comment: I found a part of solution 

count(rate(Metric_1{}[30d])) - it counts how many times value changed in 30 days

Comment: No, it doesn't. `count(rate(Metric_1{}[30d]))` will have exactly the same result as `count(Metric_1{})`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use combination of `count` and `last_over_time`:

```
count(last_over_time({__name__=~"Metric_\d"}[1d])) by (__name__)
```

Here:

- `{__name__=~"Metric_\d"}` returns all metrics with name `Metric_` followed by digit. It's regex selector, if you'll need more metrics, modify accordingly,
- `last_over_time( ... [1d])` takes last seen value during the day (24h). So even if time series marked as stale, and stopped being scraped (or in case of pushgateway, stopped being pushed) its last seen value will be returned. You can set content of `[..]` according to your needs,

  - for Grafana's panel I suggest using [`[$__range]`](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/variables/add-template-variables/#__range)
- `count( ... )` return number of time series return by inner query.